# Execute multiple SQL queries with one trip to the database in CodeIgniter 2.1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-variables, multi-query

I work with codeigniter 2.1 and I get error about SQL version
I really need to execute this code..but how to do that

The error displayed:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT rt.srt_id, rt.pub_id, d.sd_date, CASE WHEN d.sd_doc != '' THEN d' at line 2

SET @i = 0.0; SELECT rt.srt_id, rt.pub_id, d.sd_date, CASE WHEN d.sd_doc != '' THEN d.sd_doc END sd_doc, rt.total_sales, @i + rt.total_sales AS Cumulative_Total, @i:= CASE WHEN d.sd_doc = '' THEN @i + rt.total_sales ELSE 0 END AS Increment FROM d_statistics_report_temp rt INNER JOIN d_statistics_docs d ON rt.pub_id = d.sd_pub AND rt.sal_must_pay_date = d.sd_date ORDER BY rt.pub_id, d.sd_date;

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ebook\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

the SQL query is:

```
$result = $this->db->query(
    "SET @i = 0.0;
     SELECT rt.srt_id,
            rt.pub_id,
            d.sd_date,
            CASE WHEN d.sd_doc != '' THEN d.sd_doc END sd_doc,
            rt.total_sales,
            @i + rt.total_sales AS Cumulative_Total,
            @i:= CASE WHEN d.sd_doc = '' THEN @i + rt.total_sales ELSE 0 END AS Increment
     FROM d_statistics_report_temp rt
     INNER JOIN d_statistics_docs d ON rt.pub_id = d.sd_pub
                                       AND rt.sal_must_pay_date = d.sd_date
     ORDER BY rt.pub_id, d.sd_date;"
);
```

Comment: This isn't CodeIgniter specific and the message say to check the manual for the version of MySQL that _you_ have. Anyway ... missing 'AS' between the CASE statement and the field alias?

Comment: no ...code works good in sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d326c/7 and works good in phpmyadmin in local host..the problem with codeigniter

Comment: The problem isn't in CodeIgniter, but I didn't notice something at first - you're trying to execute 2 queries at a time, which isn't possible. Do `$this->db->query('SET @i = 0.0;');` first, and then the rest in a separate `query()`.

Comment: @Narf I am not sure that would work, as the first query is to set a temporary variable, but the next query would not be able to make use of it.

Comment: how to do all this code to be work together because the code is related

Comment: @xiankai I'm not sure it would work either, but it's worth trying. The only other option is using the 'mysqli' driver (which should be the case anyway) and then using `$this->db->conn_id->multi_query()`.